# codeigniter link not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter website installed on this link: `http://localhost/shivnath/`  and its working fine on this url. site has a controller name site
which is as follow

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

 /**
  * Index Page for this controller.
  *
  * Maps to the following URL
  *         http://example.com/index.php/welcome
  * - or -
  *         http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
  * - or -
  * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
  * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
  *
  * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
  * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
  * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
  */
  public function index()
  {
    $this->home();
  }


  public function home()
  {

    $this->load->view('templets/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/home');
    $this->load->view('templets/footer');

  }
}
```

When I open this link:  `localhost/shivnath/index.php/site`  site doesnt load correctly.  although its same controller loaded on this link  `localhost/shivnath/` but it works fine on this link.

Comment: I am not `CI` expert but give a try to `Site` instead of `site`

Comment: not working thanx for your suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean by does not load?You getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

use  `redirect('site/home');` instead of `$this->home();`

Comment: thank you for your responce but it also not working.  i dont uderstand that same code is behaving differently.

Comment: in your config->autoload add this `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');`

Comment: thank you for your responce but it also not gonna work. it work fine at main url but not in controller url.

Answer (score 0):

is file routes.php in config

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcom';
```

change to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
```

---

for remove index.php

file config.php -> find line 32

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and file .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of codeigniter, On codeingiter 3 you need to check that all controllers and models have there first letter as upper case on the file and class name.

And for loading your CSS and images and js

first steps autoload the url helper in application / config / autoload.php

Then in your **main directory** add a assets folder place all your css and images in that folder you can have sub folders in the assets folder.

Then try to assets the css on the header

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/stylesheet.css');?>
```

If you have not removed index.php from your config setting then each time you need to include index.php in url.

```
<?php echo base_url('index.php/assets/css/stylesheet.css');?>
```

If you remove index.php you can get some .htacess from here.https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter